# Doing nodal analysis on a circuit with a capacitor.

Tags: capacitor, nodal-analysis

[image]

I'm looking at with the switch open. I get

[image]

While going through the nodal analysis I get

[image]

V1 = 3V

Does that mean current across the resistor would then just be 1mA?

Comment: as that is a DC source and you seem to be considering steady state, the current would be 0 A.

Comment: Alright? I guess then I am extremely confused? Wouldn't be it be steady state as current wouldn't be going off to a open wire would it? How would I approach it?

Comment: Can you show your node equations?

Comment: v1/6k + v1/3k + (v1+6-12)/2k =0

Comment: Where does the "+6" come from?

Comment: From the first picture nodal analysis before the switch is thrown.
((va-36v)/5k)+va/3+va/6 = 0 

Va=6v.

Thus at V1 the voltage at t=0 is 6v.

Answer (score 1):

The left side schematic is at \$t=0^-\$ and the right side schematic is at \$t=0^+\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frWtfc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above was figured out by mere inspection. I didn't bother with nodal analysis. It was sufficient to see that from either \$V_A\$'s or \$V_B\$'s perspective, \$R_2\$, \$R_3\$, and \$R_4\$ always total out to \$2\:\text{k}\Omega\$ to ground. For the left side, this meant \$V_A=\frac13\cdot36\:\text{V}=12\:\text{V}\$ and the rest just falls out. For the right side,  \$I_{t=0^+}=\frac{12\:\text{V}-6\:\text{V}}{2\:\text{k}\Omega+2\:\text{k}\Omega}=1.5\:\text{mA}\$ so it followed that \$V_B=2\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 1.5\:\text{mA}=3\:\text{V}\$ and the rest just falls out quickly, again.

If you were doing nodal analysis for \$t=0^-\$ (left side schematic) then:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_A}{R_1}+\frac{V_A}{R_2}+\frac{V_A}{R_3}&=\frac{36\:\text{V}}{R_1}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_2}+\frac{V_B}{R_3}\\\\
\frac{V_B}{R_3}+\frac{V_B}{R_4}&=\frac{V_A}{R_3}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_4}
\end{align*}$$

Which, of course, solves out as \$V_A=12\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_B=6\:\text{V}\$. No shock. Also, since there is no current in \$R_5\$, it follows that \$V_{C_1}=6\:\text{V}\$ at \$t=0^-\$.

If you were doing nodal analysis for \$t=0^+\$ (right side schematic), and temporarily treating \$C_1\$ as a voltage source where \$V_{C_1}=6\:\text{V}\$ at \$t=0^+\$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_A}{R_2}+\frac{V_A}{R_3}&=\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_2}+\frac{V_B}{R_3}\\\\
\frac{V_B}{R_3}+\frac{V_B}{R_4}&=I_{C_1}+\frac{V_A}{R_3}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_4}\\\\
\frac{V_C}{R_5}+I_{C_1}&=\frac{12\:\text{V}}{R_5}\\\\
V_C&=V_B+V_{C_1}
\end{align*}$$

Which, of course, solves out as \$V_A=1.5\:\text{V}\$, \$V_B=3\:\text{V}\$, \$V_C=9\:\text{V}\$, and \$I_{C_1}=1.5\:\text{mA}\$. Again, no shock.

All that remains, really, is to develop these equations for \$t\gt 0\$. But that's not part of your question.

---

From the above, it's easy to show the value of \$i_x\$. And it's just as you say it is.

Comment: +1 and what would be the value of Ic(0) here? We know Ic(0-) and Ic(0+) but I'm curious about Ic(0).